# ElastiSearch Query: How to do inline "calculation" between fields, and then use it as boost variable?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Books Index with fields something like this:

```
{
    "title": "To Kill a Mockingbird",
    "summary": "To Kill a Mockingbird takes place in Alabama during the Depression..",
    "type": "book",
    "views": 36
},
{
    "title": "The Genius of Birds",
    "summary": "The Genius Of Birds shines a new light on a genuinely underrated kind..",
    "type": "book",
    "views": 10
},
{
    "title": "Handbook of Bird Biology",
    "summary": "The Handbook of Bird Biology is an essential reference for birdwatchers..",
    "type": "book",
    "views": 27
}
```

In ElasticSearch `v5.1`, below is my current simple Query which is working on it's own:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "book"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "the bird",
          "fields": [
            "title",
            "summary"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*(Searching for the words `the bird` from the fields: `title`, `summary` where the `type` must be `book`)*

This gives me a simple result based on `title` and `summary` fields. But i need it to be modified a little bit more.

Is it possible to modify the Query to look something like:

```
    ..
    "must": {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": "the bird",
        "fields": [
          "title^(0.1*views)",
          "summary"
        ]
      }
    }
    ..
```

I don't know how to call it in ES, but basically i want to **boost a field** (the `title`) by another field (the `view`).

Or in the simplest form, something like:

```
field1^(field2)
```

Comment: check this:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Aarchit Saxena for [the hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348309/elastisearch-query-how-to-do-inline-calculation-between-fields-and-then-use#comment87712763_50348309) in the comment section. Now i know it is called `field_value_factor`, and then by exploring further from there, i've now finally managed to get the query i needed.

The original query (above) has became like this now:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "type": "book"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "must": {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "the bird",
              "fields": [
                "title",
                "summary"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "views",
            "factor": 1,
            "modifier": "none",
            "missing": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost": 1,
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.